# iOS - mobile application is sending two this same request in milliseconds apart

Tags: ios, http, request

In our application we observe multiple ( two ) these same requests send from mobile application to server in milliseconds apart.

As we discuss the problem with dev team, they said they don't send two requests from an application perspective, but on the server-side, we see exactly these same two requests.

Does anybody know if iOS has this type of functionality to keep resending this same request in case of a lost connection or any other case? ( This  is milliseconds that server doesn't respond yet )

The application should send only one request, wait for response success/failure, and then resend as needed. So far as we know, there is no logic in the application itself that will trigger sending two requests from the app to the server in milliseconds apart.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: It is most likely a bug in the application. There is certainly no inherent behaviour in ios that would act as you describe.  You will need to perform debugging and perhaps even network traces to work out what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without looking at the code or knowing your network infrastructure.

What I'd suggest to do first is to run the app through a debugging proxy server like Charles, Proxyman or mitmproxy. If it shows multiple requests, most likely the app is to blame, I'd bet on a concurrency bug.

If the debugging proxy shows just one request but your server observes two, you'll have to check your network infrastructure, it might be that some load balancer or reverse proxy is configured incorrectly.